# converting a json file to csv

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to convert a Postman output file from JSON to a CSV.  In the past I have just used a json to csv converter but I have some sensitive data for a particular file and do not feel comfortable using an online tool.  Searched for some code that might be able to help me with this.  When I run this in visual studio I do not see a file created.  I will admit I have not done any C# in years and all I really am using it for is to convert this one json file to a csv.  Can someone please take a quick look at this code and let me know what I am doing wrong?  The jsonInput is not the actual input I am using.  Just want to use that as an example.  I plan to use a filename for the input but can try figuring that out on my own.  Just hoping to get some help to just get a file created.

````
```
using Aspose.Cells;
using Aspose.Cells.Utility;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json;

// load JSON data

string jsonInput = "[{'nodeId':1,'reputation':1134},{'nodeId':2,'reputation':547},{'nodeId':3,'reputation':1703},{'nodeId':4,'reputation':-199},{'nodeId':5,'reputation':-306},{'nodeId':6,'reputation':-49},{'nodeId':7,'reputation':1527},{'nodeId':8,'reputation':1223}]";

// create a blank Workbook object
var workbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();

// access default empty worksheet
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

// set JsonLayoutOptions for formatting
var layoutOptions = new JsonLayoutOptions();
layoutOptions.ArrayAsTable = true;

// import JSON data to CSV
Aspose.Cells.Utility.JsonUtility.ImportData(jsonInput, worksheet.Cells, 0, 0, layoutOptions);

// save CSV file
workbook.Save("Test.csv", SaveFormat.Csv);
```
````

Comment: JSON is generally a multi dimensional file format, CSV is 2 dimensional.  How are you going to represent a child/parent relationship 4 levels down in CSV?  It's just not practical.

Comment: That's not creating a CSV, it's creating an excel document. a CSV is just a text file. Your first very basic troubleshooting task is to run the code in debug mode and see what happens